# How to set a default date dynamically in DateField

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to add a field `today + 7 days` as a default value in the Django DateField.

That's How I'm doing.

```
date_validity = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today() + timedelta(days=7))
```

But that's giving me the problem
One thing is Field is being altered every time when we run `makemigrations/migrate` command however we are not making any changes. How can I set that up accurately?

Comment: [Your answer of question in this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65658116/django-3-dynamic-default-value-in-model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following on the model to set a date when none is given/set.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs)
    if not self.date_validity:
        self.date_validity = datetime.date.today() + timedelta(days=7)
    super().save(*args,**kwargs) # Or super(MyModel, self).save(*args,**kwargs) # for older python versions.
```

To get the date for the field.

```
def get_default_date():
    return datetime.date.today() + timedelta(days = 7)
```

And then in the field:

```
date_validity = models.DateField(default=get_default_date)
```

Possible duplicate of:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2771701/18020941

Comment: That looks great. But is there any way to handle it thru the Django DateField default argument?

Comment: It has a problem, that will alter the date value every time we save the object. Like if we save the object date validity would be 2 Sep but if again we save the object tomorrow that would be 3 Sep. And that's not the accurate.

Comment: @atropabelladona edited my answer to fit your needs. It does not set a new date every time, since the date field will already be populated. There was an `if` in place to check against this.

Comment: Yeah, Correct. I should do that way to handle that.

Comment: In get_default_date() datetime.date.now() is not accurate. Because type object 'datetime.date' has no attribute 'now'

That should be `datetime.date.today()`